# Pandas not outputting anything after successful deployment

Tags: python, pandas

When I run this script, I do not get an output. It appears as if it is successful as I do not get any errors telling me otherwise. When I run the notebook, a cell appears below the 5th cell, indicating that the script ran successfully, but there's nothing populated. All of my auth is correct as when I use the same auth in postman to pull tag data values, it's successful. This script used to run fine and output a table in addition to a graph.

What gives? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sample dataset when pulling tag data values from the Azure API

```
    "c": 100,
    "s": "opc",
    "t": "2021-06-11T16:45:55.04Z",
    "v": 80321248.5
```

#Code

```
import pandas as pd
from modules.services_factory import ServicesFactory
from modules.data_service import TagDataValue
from modules.model_service import ModelService
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil.parser

pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

#specify tag list, start and end times here
taglist = ['c41f-ews-systemuptime']
starttime = '2021-06-10T14:00:00Z'
endtime = '2021-06-10T16:00:00Z'

# Get data and model services.
services = ServicesFactory('local.settings.production.json')
data_service = services.get_data_service()

tagvalues = []
for tag in taglist:
    for tagvalue in data_service.get_tag_data_values(tag, dateutil.parser.parse(starttime), dateutil.parser.parse(endtime)):
        tagvaluedict = tagvalue.__dict__
        tagvaluedict['tag_id'] = tag
        tagvalues.append(tagvaluedict)

df = pd.DataFrame(tagvalues)
df = df.pivot(index='t',columns='tag_id')

fig = df['v'].plot()
fig.update_traces(connectgaps=True)
fig.show()
```

[image: Please view image]

Comment: screenshots is not way to build a question on SO....  can you provide sample data from dataframe before you try to create a plotly graph

Comment: My apologies, this is my first help request... I'll adjust the original request to address this comment

Comment: Hopefully that's better...